# Android Kotlin : TextView.text not working as expected

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, textview

I have an app that makes user sign in with Firebase if they are not already signed in. If user signs in their user profile info shows properly. Upon closing the app and reopening the user name and email does not set and goes to my defaulted text. But if I sign out and back in it will show. I feel like it has something to do with updating ui but stuck.

I can post code after my lunch break is over if needed

*update with code*

This is the relevent code in MainActivity this is where I check if user is logged in if so allow them to go from there if not to start signin activity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

val TAG = "MainActivity"

var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
var mUser: FirebaseUser? = null
var userEmailTV: TextView? = null
var userDispNameTV: TextView? = null
val RC_SIGN_IN = 123

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

}

 override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    mUser = mAuth?.currentUser

    if (mUser != null) {

        userEmailTV = findViewById<View>(R.id.userEmail) as TextView?
        userEmailTV?.text = mUser?.email
        userDispNameTV = findViewById<View>(R.id.userName) as TextView?
        userDispNameTV?.text = mUser?.displayName

        Log.i(TAG, "User Display Name : ${mUser?.displayName}")
        Log.i(TAG, "Users Email :  ${mUser?.email}")

    } else {
        startActivityForResult(
                // Get an instance of AuthUI based on the default app
                AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN)
    }


}
```

This is the layout info that holds the user profile info inside the navigation drawer

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:text="Username"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="youremail@something.com"/>
```

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: K like I said I can after lunch. But till then any idea why in logcat it would show the correct info but won’t display on ui unless the user has signed on after opening app? I feel like if it shows in loggcat it should display on the UI

Comment: There must be something in the code that is changing the value. So do post the code i will have a look over it.

Comment: I have updated post with relevent code if I am missing something let me know and I'll add it

Comment: Why are you initiating the views in the onStart method? They are supposed to be in the onCreate Method. In the onStart you just have to find the value from it.

Comment: so move the             userEmailTV = findViewById<View>(R.id.userEmail) as TextView?
 to onCreate and set text in onstart?

Comment: Yes you should try that.

Comment: didn't change a thing by moving that

Comment: Look like the logic that checks if user is logged in should be in onResume method. And yes the findView calls better in onCreate

Comment: That still doesn’t explain why the Log.i(tag, ...... code outputs correct data for user but only is displayed correctly if start activity for result has been ran in the current life cycle. It is checking if user is logged in correctly finds correct user data. But if application has been closed, even though mUser?.email contains a String when I try to set text to TextView it says that value is null.  It’s like I need to make a virtual switch and if off turn on startactivity(MainActivity, MainActivity) is switch on ok TextView set text.

Comment: Is that the only place where you set that text?

Comment: Also, have you tried stepping over the code in the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My theory after much trial and error and research is..... that this problem is not due to the TextView being initialized in the wrong spot as others thought in the comments above but.  Due to the fact that the navigation header view has not had time to inflate. I will work on coding of initializing the nav header then the TextView and edit with results.

**Edit**

Here is what I did to make it work.
I added

```
        uemail = findViewById<View>(R.id.nav_view) as NavigationView
    navHead = uemail.getHeaderView(0)
    tvEmail = navHead.findViewById(R.id.userEmail) as TextView
    tvDisplayName = navHead.findViewById(R.id.userName) as TextView
    tvEmail.text = mUser?.email
    tvDisplayName.text = mUser?.displayName
```

I placed that inside of a function that I called inside of both onCreate and onStart. If I didn't it would only populate after signing in or not at all. This way it populates the correct data and all the time. I found it has something to do with after Android Studio uses a recyclerview for the nav view after 23.1 or something like that.

Comment: Looks like a bad theory. Inflation works on the main thread, as well as activity callbacks, so there is no possibility that onStart executed before onCreate finished.

Comment: I initialized the TextView in onCreate and onStart and still get an error stating that the TextView cant be null. Even though I am setting a value (the logcat proves this) to the TextView. The latest error doesn’t say TextView can’t be set to null just that TextView is null. That leads me to bilieve that since I am initiating the TextView but not the specific nav header it is trying to set text before it has time to load. This would also explain why the TextView would only display correct info after doing a startactivityforresult to login. Once it has a chance to inflate the view and come back

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "findView" succeeded? Try calling it on navigation header view receiver